# Match Column and Fill Next Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm very new to excel so please hang with me.

I have 2 columns that hold all of my products and their descriptions (Columns A & B in picture).

I'm trying to have it so whenever I type in a model number into Active Products (Column C in picture), my excel automatically searches column A, matches it to the model in column C and copies the description from column B to column D. Does this make any sense?

Basically, I have 20,000 models and their descriptions in columns A & B and whenever I put in a model number in column C, my script searches column A and copies over the description that matches that model in the B column over to column D.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VLOOKUP` for this. Just fill your D column with the following formula. I always get this wrong, but I think it should be this. Of course, you'll want to make sure the "2" matches whatever row you start with for your fill.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, A:B, 2)
```

Let me know if that doesn't work and I can fix it, though.

If you want it to be pretty, wrap it with an `IF`.

```
=IF(C2 = "", "", VLOOKUP(C2, A:B, 2))
```